# Текст без переноса строки

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Всем привет!

Как сделать так , чтобы слова были на всю ширину блока?
Как в WORD. То есть даже пусть 1 или 2 буквы от слова будут на 1-ой строке а остальная часть слова переносится на 2-ую строку. Вообщем говоря Полное заполнение блока текстом.

Вот КОД

[Ссылка на JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fvaeco6o/)

```
<!-- vygoda wrapper -->
<div class="vygoda" id="vygoda">
    <div class="title">Выгодная покупка</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="vygoda-item">
            <div class="vygoda-img"></div>
            <div class="vygoda-content">
                <h2>Детская и спортивная площадки:</h2>
                <p>
                    Вам больше не надо тратить время на поиски 
                    просторной и безопасной  детской площадки. Она 
                    будет прямо около дома на огороженной и 
                    территории. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vygoda-item">
            <div class="vygoda-img"></div>
            <div class="vygoda-content">
                <h2>Персональная парковка:</h2>
                <p>
                    В нашем доме запланирована бесплатная 
                    закрытая стоянка. Теперь Вам и Вашим гостям 
                    больше не придется искать место для парковки 
                    автомобиля.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="vygoda-item">
            <div class="vygoda-img"></div>
            <div class="vygoda-content">
                <h2>Огороженная территория:</h2>
                <p>
                    Наш жилой комплекс является закрытой 
                    территорией. Вам больше не нужно волноваться 
                    за безопасность своих детей. Транспортные 
                    средства также защищены.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vygoda-item">
            <div class="vygoda-img"></div>
            <div class="vygoda-content">
                <h2>Высокий уровень теплоизоляции:</h2>
                <p>
                    Мощные стены в два кирпича с толстым слоем 
                    утеплителя делают дом неуязвимым к холодам. 
                    В Вашей квартире будет всегда тепло и уютно.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div><!--/. vygoda wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь это то, что тебе нужно.

```
p {text-align: justify;}
```

Comment: точно) оказалось всё просто.

Answer (score 0):

Более полный ответ и учитывает переносы:

```css
p {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
Как сделать так , чтобы слова были на всю ширину блока? Как в WORD. То есть даже пусть 1 или 2 буквы от слова будут на 1-ой строке а остальная часть слова переносится на 2-ую строку. Вообщем говоря Полное заполнение блока текстом. Как сделать так , чтобы слова были на всю ширину блока? Как в WORD. То есть даже пусть 1 или 2 буквы от слова будут на 1-ой строке а остальная часть слова переносится на 2-ую строку. Вообщем говоря Полное заполнение блока текстом. Как сделать так , чтобы слова были на всю ширину блока? Как в WORD. То есть даже пусть 1 или 2 буквы от слова будут на 1-ой строке а остальная часть слова переносится на 2-ую строку. Вообщем говоря Полное заполнение блока текстом.
</p>
```

Comment: Можете добавить, пожалуйста, также запускаемый пример для большей наглядности?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov готово.